# salutation for formal letters

Tags: salutations

> I was taught in school that Sir is the appropriate addressing for a formal letter to say a head of institution or principal. Dear sir shows familiarity which is not preferred. Does this hold today?

Answer (score 2):

*Dear Sir* is the normal formal salutation if you know that you are addressing a man. *Sir* alone is used, at least in the UK, only on rare occasions. It might be found, for example, as a saluation in a letter to the editor of a newspaper, and which is intended for publication.